# Thread synchronisation among multithreads accessing singleton object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to find out if there is a better way for the code below in terms of robust code and clean code.

```
// Encryption is singleton via IoC
public class Encryption{

        private volatile ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _blobs = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        private object _encryptedDataLock = new object();
        public string CreateEncryptedData(string key)
        {
            string encryptedData = string.Empty;

            if (_cloudBlobs.ContainsKey(key))
                encryptedData = _blobs[key];

            lock (_encryptedDataLock)
            {

                if (!_cloudBlobs.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    encryptedData = CalulateEncryptedData();
                    _blobs.TryAdd(key, encryptedData);

                    return encryptedData;

                }
            }

            return encryptedData;
        }
}
```

**Update**

I am looking for solution that is not using lock object, double checking, volatile, as less code as possible explicitly.

Comment: `_blobs` doesn't need to be volatile, as it's never written to. You could make it `readonly` also.

Comment: But it has `_blobs.TryAdd`

Comment: Doesn't matter. That's not how volatile works

Comment: Ok, Can you elaborate or provide a link so I can fully understand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this: http://www.albahari.com/threading/. You never assign to the `_blobs` field.

Answer (score 0):

If two threads call `CreateEncryptedData` with the same key at the same time, there are three possible outcomes:

1. `CalulateEncryptedData()` is called exactly once, both threads get the result, and that result is stored in `_blobs`.
2. `CalulateEncryptedData()` is called twice, but the result of one of the calls is discarded. Both threads get the same result, and that result is also stored in `_blobs`.
3. `CalulateEncryptedData()` is called twice, and both threads get different results. One of the results is stored in `_blobs`. Obviously this is undesirable.

If you need case 1, then you need a separate lock object, but you can write it like this:

```
public string CreateEncryptedData(string key)
{
    if (_blobs.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
        return value;

    lock (_encryptedDataLock)
    {
        return _blobs.GetOrAdd(key, x => CalulateEncryptedData());
    }
}
```

If case 2 is OK, you can further simplify to this:

```
public string CreateEncryptedData(string key)
{
    return _blobs.GetOrAdd(key, x => CalulateEncryptedData());
}
```